# How to make sidebar always visible in the Semantic UI

Tags: css, semantic-ui

How to make sidebar always visible in the Semantic UI?
Simply adding the "active" css class works, but messes up page layout.

`There is a working example on` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9EK3J/).

Comment: Do you have a code example you can share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This issue is officially fixed since 2015 so the definite answer [can be found below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293378/how-to-make-sidebar-always-visible-in-the-semantic-ui#33639025).**

Just for reference… in *2014* I had to do following things to make this work:

1. add `active` css class to the sidebar
2. add html code:

   ```
   <div class="segment">
       <div class="container" style="margin:1.5em 1.5em 1.5em 325px">
           <!-- content here -->
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Do you have meanwhile any other fix for this problem beside the style workaround? I am having exactly the same problem and I wouldn't like to go for inline styles.

Answer (score 14):

This has been officially [fixed](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/649#issuecomment-69258661).

```
<div class="ui vertical inverted left visible sidebar menu"> 
  <a class="item">
    <i class="home icon"></i>
    Home
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="block layout icon"></i>
    Topics
  </a>
</div>
<div class="pusher">This is some content.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a nicer solution than mike's.

Comment: Thank you! This is not obvious from the docs ATM, but if you want to have always-expanded sidebar in SemanticUI, this is the way to go.